# Mule 4 : Salesforce : API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, mule4

Scenario : Mule 4 and Salesforce Integration.

1. Created a developer account in Salesforce.
2. Created a Custom Object in Salesforce for loading data via Mulesoft.
3. In mule 4 using a Salesforce Query component and providing the SF username, password and security token and did a 'TEST CONNECTION'.

Problem : Getting the Error :

```
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner
  org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner
  Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner
  Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner
  Caused by: [UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG'
   exceptionMessage='API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner'
   extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
  ]
  ]
```

When I checked for solutions I found the following steps:

1. Go to Setup->Manage Users -> Profiles-> System Administrator-> Edit Profile.
2. But in Administer Preferences I do not see the enable API option.

[image]

But when I check under Administration Settings, I do not see an option to enable the API.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your license level (Platinum?) does not have API management. Consult with your Mulesoft sale representative.
I guess it because we have such license and we do not have API management.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to API Manager.

Comment: I have created a trial salesforce developer account. So where can I check license details and how can I connect from mule to consume data?

Comment: I believe that developer account does not have API management. API management in this case belongs to owner of this training site who, by default and for training purposes allows developers to create apps/APIs but not manage them.

Answer (score 0):

Signup for free Salesforce Developer trial account to use the API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickstart_dev_org.htm